# Why is this .sh script run on CentOS but not on Ubuntu?

Tags: scripts

I'm trying to run this simple script that succesfully run on CentOS but not on Ubuntu.
The script start succesfully but fails to get into the if condition and straight moving to the else.

Is there any syntax error with the if loop?
The idea is to get the content of filename output2.txt into a variable named **value** (is that command OK?) and check if subtext **512.00GB** include in the text (in **value**)...

```
sudo msecli -L > output2.txt
value=`cat output2.txt`
check="512.00GB"
#echo "$value"
if [[ "$value" == *"$check"* ]]; then
  echo "The SSD is 512GB"
sudo msecli -L >> output.txt
sudo nvme delete-ns -n 1 /dev/nvme0
sudo nvme delete-ns -n 1 /dev/nvme1
sleep 1
sudo msecli -N -q 100 -n /dev/nvme0 -r
sleep 1
sudo msecli -N -q 100 -n /dev/nvme1 -r
sleep 2
sudo reboot
else
sudo msecli -L >> output.txt
echo "***** The SSD is READY!!! *****"
fi
```

The error we get is in line 5 [[, which seems the if command is not working.

I used the following example I found on the web for searching subtext in a text:

```
#example
#STR='GNU/Linux is an operating system'
#SUB='Linux'
#if [[ "$STR" == *"$SUB"* ]]; then
#  echo "It's there."
#fi
```

Comment: Consider using grep (especially grep -F) to search a file for a pattern (string).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If your script doesn't start with a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) line like

```
#!/bin/bash
```

it may be run by `/bin/sh` (see "[Which shell interpreter runs a script with no shebang?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/373223/which-shell-interpreter-runs-a-script-with-no-shebang/373229#373229)" for details).

Ubuntu uses [dash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almquist_shell#dash) for `/bin/sh` and dash doesn't support Bash-specific syntax like `[[...]]` so you get an error.

CentOS may use Bash for `/bin/sh` so this works there.

Add

```
#!/bin/bash
```

as the first line of your script to make sure it is run by Bash.

Comment: Or run `bash script.sh`

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks. I've added that to my answer.

Comment: Thank you @FlorianDiesch!